# documentation for lazy for-comprehensions in Python

Tags: python, generator, list-comprehension

It looks like this construct in Python is not lazy:

```
g1 = ["'"+x+"'" for x in f2]
```

and this one is:

```
g2 = ("'"+x+"'" for x in f2)
```

since g2 has a `next()` method and g1 does not.

Where is this documented? I can't seem to find the relevant page in the python docs, not sure what to look up.

Comment: First one is called `list comprehension` and second one is called `generator expression`, I hope that may help you in search.

Comment: http://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#generator-expressions

Comment: Having a `next()` is not a dispositive test of lazy evaluation. Consider `iter(range(1000))` The returned iterator has a `next()` method, but the object is still a full list evaluated and allocated before it is returned (at least in Py 2.X; Py 3k+ is a different story.)

Answer (score 6):

You are looking for [list displays](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#list-displays) and [generator expressions](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#generator-expressions). The first form is called a "list comprehension", and is a specialized form of defining a list.

As for the second form, the generator expression, this is what the documentation has to say:

> A generator expression yields a new generator object. Its syntax is the same as for comprehensions, except that it is enclosed in parentheses instead of brackets or curly braces.

Comment: thank you!!! I like relying on documented behavior rather than what I think is the right behavior.

Answer (score 2):

You might want to look here: http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0289/

This is the PEP that describes the generator expressions and the rationale behind it.